# Disable Tasks in Chatter Feeds

Tags: tasks, chatter-feed

With Salesforce.com Spring ’13 Release we got the feature: "Chatter feed notification on task creation"
and in order to turn it off:

Click Your Name > Setup > Customize > Chatter > Settings and  de-select "Tasks in Feed"

Now "Tasks in Feed" checkbox is not there anymore , how can i disable chatter feed notification on task creation?

I have tried:
Setup > Customize > Chatter  > Feed Tracking, scroll down to Tasks, and disable feed tracking for Tasks 
but it doesn´t turn off task feeds.

Thanks in advantage for any advice.